# Creating GUI in OSGi

Tags: user-interface, osgi

What is the Easiest way to set up a interactive GUI in the OSGi framework.
I need some data to display in real-time too.
I loved the idea Riena presented, but I seem to have a hard time understanding their concept(tutorials).
Any other options I can consider?

Thanx.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the Eclipse Rich Client platform (RCP). It's all OSGi-based, and provides lots of GUI APIs. You could display your data yourself using a Canvas, or you could use BIRT, although BIRT is also very complex.

Comment: What is the different between RCP and RAP?

Comment: Java GUI application vs. Ajax based web app.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your application, you could also implement your GUI with HTML5 and Javascript. In this model the  OSGi framework is running as a background service with an HTTP server. You GUI then uses some interface (usually REST) to communicate with the server. There are some awkward aspects:

- launching, launching a server and then a browser on a URL is platform dependent (but so is starting Java)
- users can easily switch away from your app, desktop apps tend to linger around, potentially forgetting that you have the server still running
- More complex communication between business logic and GUI

There are also a number of advantages:

- Best GUI environment possible
- Well known technology
- Zillions of examples
- Clean cut between GUI and business logic
- Simple to make multi-user

With HTML5 it is possible to built a single-page application that works very well with a back-end server, take for example a look at AngularJS from Google.